# Splash Screen анимация

Tags: android

Пишу приложение для android.
Столкнулся с проблемой создания загрузочного экрана.

У меня иеются 4 png файла с разными состояниями объекта, как из них сделать анимацию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот загуглил, на официальном сайте есть туториал:
http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html

Comment: сенкс

я тупо не находил этого(

Comment: @Eugene, если ответ вам помог, отметьте его галочкой.

Comment: бойтесь out of memory :) если картинки большие.